# Google Maps Animated Heat Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I was wondering if it would be possible to animate the heat map I've set up for my Google Map. It was easy enough to set up  the google map and add the heat map to it. But it looks quite boring. I wanted to add somekind of a pulse effect to the heat map.
Thanks

Comment: I guess CSS3 animation and box-shadow can be used to alter the custom maker's parent element, but that would be quite dull.

Comment: I think animating the opacity would be a very nice yet lightweight effect. There are multiple example online for adjusting opacity, so you'd just need to stick it in an interval.

Answer (score 4):

It's straightforward to animate the heatmap's appearance. The following example sets a custom array of gradient colors and modulates its size. The result is sort of a pulsing effect. You may tweak the colors to your liking in the `modulateGradient` function or even add changes to the heatmap's opacity. Note, however, that depending on the size of your data set the animation might have a considerable performance impact.

#### HTML

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

#### JS

```
var map, pointarray, heatmap;
var gradient, gradientStep = -1;

var taxiData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687)
];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: pointArray
    });

    heatmap.setMap(map);
    setGradient();

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', modulateGradient);
}

function setGradient() {
    gradient = [
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
        'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
        'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
        'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
        'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ];
    heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
}

function modulateGradient() {
    var modulator = function() {
        var newGradient = gradient.slice(0, heatmap.get('gradient').length + gradientStep);

        if (newGradient.length == gradient.length || newGradient.length == 7) {
            gradientStep *= -1;
        }

        heatmap.set('gradient', newGradient);

        setTimeout(modulator, 100);
    };

    setTimeout(modulator, 100);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can find a live version of the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px8kgvjb/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kind of pulsing effect by changing the radius size of the heat map layer.

First let's make a `var smallRadius` and `var bigRadius` and set values to them; e.g. `smallRadius = 40;` `bigRadius = 80;`

then add the radius size to your `var mapOptions`  and set it to `smallRadius`.

Then create an `animateRadius()` function which changes the radius value from `smallRadius` to `bigRadius` if it is set to `smallRadius`, else set the radius to `smallRadius`.

Then set the function to run every second or so by surrounding the function in a `setInterval()`.

So Basically this:

```
var smallRadius = 40;
var bigRadius = 80;

    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            radius: smallRadius
        };

//animate radius function

setInterval(function animateRadius()
         {
             if (heatMap.get('radius') === smallRadius)
            {
                heatMap.set('radius', bigRadius);
            }
            else
            {
                heatMap.set('radius', smallRadius);
            }
         }, 1000); // changes radius every 1 second
```

Obviously you can change the `smallRadius` and `bigRadius` to whatever values you want.