# Can the built-in heatmap layer in Google Maps API be optimized for animation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, heatmap

**Context**: 
The built-in heatmap layer in Google Maps API doesn't have native support for animations, so I've created my own animations using `requestAnimationFrame` with calls to the Maps API to set the next frame's data. Each frame uses ~2500 data points to render the heatmap and maxes out around 4000 data points.

**The problem**:
My animation has jank every 5-10 cycles. I don't need the animation to render 60fps, but I do want the framerate to be consistent and each step to be <=100ms. In Devtools, the janky animation frames give me this error at the top of call stack: "Warning: Recurring handler took # ms."

**My proposed cause of the problem**:
The dev console shows memory leaks,* minor GC, major GC, and DOM GC correlating to Maps API calls. The DOM GC in particular is correlated to the animation jank. (*JS Heap, Nodes, and Listeners increase linearly).

**Why I'm asking the question**:
I'm fairly new to Google Maps API, requestAnimationFrame, and memory management in JavaScript, so first of all I want to make sure I'm understanding the problem correctly. Secondly, I want to see if there is a way to optimize the heatmap layer for animations, or if my approach is misguided.

**Most relevant resources I've consulted**:
[Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)
[Google's guide to web performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/why-performance-matters/)
[StackOverflow question that asks about very basic, short Maps API heatmap animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918752/google-maps-animated-heat-map)

**Code**
All within a d3.csv('data').
Establish recursive requestAnimationFrame:

```
const periodDuration = 100; // ms
const timeStart = performance.now();

const frameTick = timestamp => {
  if (timestamp - timeStart >= periodDuration) {
    timeStart = timestamp;
    transitionToNextPeriod(); // shown in next code snippet
  }  
  requestAnimationFrame(frameTick);
};

requestAnimationFrame(frameTick);
```

`transitionToNextPeriod` increments time, then filters data, and ends by setting heatmap with updated data:

```
function transitionToNextPeriod() {
  let batchedData = [],
      currPeriodData = [],
      addMin = 0;
      prevMin = min,
      prevDate = date,
      currMin = 0;

  // batch the next 'x' # of mins for one batchedData call after `while` loop
  while (++addMin <= 7){
    if (prevMin + addMin === 60){
      if (hour + 1 === 24){
        hour = 0;
        date++;
      } else {
        hour++
      } 
    }

    // Now with current minute, filter data and add to batchedData
    currMin = ((prevMin + addMin) % 60);

    let newTime = `${hour}:${zeroPad(currMin)}`;

    // Filter based on current time
    let currFilter = dayData.filter( d => d.StartTime.indexOf( ` ${newTime}` ) !== -1);

    prevPeriodData = prevPeriodData.filter( d => d.EndTime.indexOf( ` ${newTime}` ) === -1 );

    batchedData = [...batchedData, ...currFilter ];
  } // End while

  batchedData = [...batchedData, ...prevPeriodData];  
  prevPeriodData = batchedData;
  min = currMin;

  // Update the maps.LatLng data with new data, then set heatmap data
  batchedData.forEach( (d,i) => {
    // Check for last datum in current period
    if (i + 1 === batchedData.length){
      heatmap.setData(currPeriodData); // PROBLEM: about every 7th call to setData results in jank
    } else {
      currPeriodData.push(new google.maps.LatLng( d.Lat , d.Long ));
    }
  })
} // End transitionToNextPeriod()
```